# get function output mathematica

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica

I have defined the function:

```
g[x_] = TransformedDistribution[ u + v , {u \[Distributed] ParetoDistribution[1, 1], v \[Distributed] ParetoDistribution[1, 1]}];

PDF[dist,x]
```

However, when I want to integrate `g[x]` from k to infinity :

```
Integrate[g[x] , {x,k , \[Infinity] } ]
```

Mathematica does not output anything.

Any recommendations on how to solve this or how I could get the function that was outputted when I first defined `g[x]` and then doing the integration ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have your function syntax wrong, try this:

```
 g[x_] = PDF[
       TransformedDistribution[
             u + v, {u \[Distributed] ParetoDistribution[1, 1], 
                     v \[Distributed] ParetoDistribution[1, 1]}], x]
```

when you integrate you need to add the condition that k is real:

```
Integrate[g[x], {x, k, Infinity}, Assumptions -> Element[k, Reals]]


         1                          k<=2
        (2 (k + Log[-1 + k]))/k^2   k>2
```